# Is there simple way to get array from td elements on page? (node.js/cheerio/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am using node.js/cheerio (the same as jQuery syntax) to parse the page.
And when I am using:

```
$ = cheerio.load(body);
console.log($('.td-title a').text());
```

I have in my console very long string from words "mainaboutcontactusprofile" etc. How can I make an array of td text?

Answer (score 7):

None of the answers provided worked for me, but this did.

```
let arr = $('.td-title a').toArray().map((x) => { return $(x).text()});
```

Credit: [Github](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/613)

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery's `map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

```js
console.log($("td").map(function(){ return this.textContent}).get());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using jQuery's $.map() function for this. It creates an array based on a matched set of elements:

```
var textArray = $('.td-title a').map( function(index, domElement) {
   return domElement.innerText;   //each element input gets turned into text output
});
console.log( textArray );
```

See http://api.jquery.com/map/ for more details

Answer (score 0):

in javascript 
simply document.getElementsByTagName("td") **return an array** of all td.

Using jQuery you should use something like $('#table1 td')